# Angular: Using $scope vs calling a controller attribute

Tags: angularjs

I've been reading the ng-book and just worked through the Code School Angular course the other day and am confused about when to use `$scope` in a controller and when to use an attribute of the controller.

In the code school course, the controllers were setup like this:

```
app.controller('LibraryController', function(){
  this.books = getBooks //some function that gets an array
});
```

But in the ng-book and elsewhere, I've only seen this done as a scope:

```
app.controller('LibraryController', function($scope){
  $scope.books = getBooks //some function that gets an array
})
```

From what I can tell, these two approaches are exactly the same. The first is used in the view like this:

```
<div ng-controller="LibraryController as libraryCtrl">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="book in libraryCtrl.books">
```

While the second would be

```
<div ng-controller="LibraryController">
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="book in books">
```

Am I not understanding something fundamental here? Is there a difference in these two approaches and why is the `$scope` approach used almost exclusively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two reasons why the scope approach is used more than the `controller as` approach:

1. The scope approach is the only one that has been existing for a long time. It's only since version 1.2 (IIRC) that the "controller as" syntax was introduced. Most people got used to the traditional way, most example were written that way.
2. The handling of `this` in JavaScript is a nightmare (IMHO). You have to read the documentation of ever callback function used to make sure that `this` doesn't change when the callback is called. Using the scope doesn't have this problem.

Comment: this is their official reasoning for the difference in the tut. Seems like just a way to isolate things when teaching: http://help.codeschool.com/discussions/shaping-up-with-angularjs/57-out-of-date-for-new-course

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use `$scope` because you are within the context of a Controller and it makes no sense to address it explicitly on each reference to a scope attribute